# My tablet can't update coc so I can't play on it

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, install

I tried to delete the game and Re install it but that's not wining eiter it's been like this since the update yesterday ad it says installing but it isn't what do I do it's the only thing I can play it on and I was in middle of war

Comment: Your tablet is an iPad, I assume?

Comment: Please see my comment below. This is the fix as I have used it on three of my own devices and used it to help others with the same problem as well.

Answer (score 1):

When you delete the app make sure and select the option that mentions removing all data from your device and game center. Then try resetting the device. Hold down the home and button and the top button until the device restarts.

Then go to the app store and download it from your "updates". If this does not work, repeat the process and attempt to download the app from the regular search results or from the top grossing apps within the app store.